# Android Simple Gallery Focused Item Issue

Tags: android, focus, imageview, gallery

I have a gallery that I use to display some ImageViews. I'd like to know which image in the gallery is currently highlighted/focused.

So far, setOnItemClickListener only fires if I actually click on the images. If I scroll through the images, a new image takes focus. I want to know which image that is.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want the View or id in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Get the images number in the list](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedView%28%29)

[Get the image (view) it self](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#getSelectedView%28%29)